# Firebase data order

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class as seen Below:

```
public class GlobalHighScore {
String name;
int score;

public GlobalHighScore(String name, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.score = score;
}


public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
}
```

And here I try to make a data receiving.

```
DatabaseReference scoresRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Highscores");    
scoresRef.child("GlobalHighScore").orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);
    scoresRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Iterable<DataSnapshot> keys = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot key : keys) {
                if(i == 10)
                    break;
                orderName[i].setText(key.getValue().toString());
                i++;
            }
        }
```

When I am doing this, `key.getValue().toString()` returns json formatted String but I want "name" and "score" seperately. Also, my data is not sorted eventhough I make it sorted.

```
scoresRef.child("GlobalHighScore").orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);
```

I think I having problem here.

Edit: When I order by "score", it gives data according to date.

Last form is

```
 final TextView[] orderScore = {firstscore, secondscore, thirdscore, fourthscore, fifthscore, sixthscore, seventhscore, eightscore, ninthscore, tenthscore};
    final TextView[] orderName = {firstname, secondname, thirdname, fourthname, fifthname, sixthname, seventhname, eightname, ninthname, tenthname};

    DatabaseReference scoresRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Highscores").child("GlobalHighScore");
    scoresRef.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);
    scoresRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            int i = 0;
            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                if(i == 10)
                    break;
                String name = data.child("name").getValue().toString();
                String score = data.child("score").getValue().toString();
                orderName[i].setText(name);
                orderScore[i].setText(score);
                i++;
            }
        }
```

It gives no data record at all.

Comment: What do you get when you order by score? Please clarify more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 DatabaseReference scoresRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Highscores").child("GlobalHighScore");
Query q=scoresRef.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);    
q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
          String score=datas.child("score").getValue().toString();
        }
    }
```

Since you want the name and the score alone you can do the above, to be able to retrieve them alone.

`.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);`, using this you will get the first 10, nodes that have the child `score`.

`limitToFirst(10) //to get the first 10 of a specific child`

`limitToLast(10) //to get the Last 10 of a specific child`

Comment: Thank you the seperating name and score well applied but still having problem with ordering can you check the edit

Comment: please do as I did u are adding the condition above the listener. It needs to be like this `scoresRef.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {`  and not like this .......`scoresRef.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(10);`

Comment: please do the same as in the edit now in the answer, it should work

Comment: still out of whack. I tried to get log but it doesnt give anything too. Maybe this gives some clue from log? W/PersistentConnection: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "score"' at Highscores/GlobalHighScore to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Answer (score 0):

When you are using the following line of code:

```
Iterable<DataSnapshot> keys = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
```

The childrens that you are getting when iterating are actual objects, not Strings. Using `toString()` method doesn't make any sense because you cannot cast an Object to a String and expect to get the values within it. That's why you are getting that "json formatted Strings". So what are you getting when iterating are actual maps. So to get the `name` and `score` you need to iterate through the map and use: `map.get("name");` and `map.get("score");`.

You don't need to change the entire code, your code is fine. Just solve this minor issue.

Comment: That side handled. Still stuck at ordering.

Comment: I gave you some informations to basically understand what was wrong in your code and why you were getting "json formatted Strings". What is the problem now regarding ordering?